How To Use Spark Submit Operator With Cassandra Remote Server In Apache Airflow
I'm working airflow into the Docker container on WindowsPC. I have some problems with apache airflow spark submit operator. I want to write data to a remote Cassandra server.
When I was using df.write.save() I was getting An error occured while calling o41.save.
The strange thing is, that I can read data and show schema, but I can't save the data. Is there any opinion about it?
And also I want to share my spark configuration;
spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .master ("local[*]")
        .appName("example")
        .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host","10.0.0.1") \
        .config("spark.cassandra.connection.port","9042") \
        .config("spark.cassandra.auth.username","pc1") \
        .config("spark.cassandra.auth.password","1234") \
        .config("spark.jars.packages","/opt/spark/jars/spark-cassandra-connector_2.12-3.4.0.jars") \
        .getOrCreate()

I want to write CSV data from Docker to the remote Cassandra server with airflow and spark process.

You didn't provide (1) the full error message with (2) the accompanying full stack trace and (3) a minimal sample code that replicates the issue so I'm going to assume that there are missing dependencies in your app.
I should note that since Spark 2.5, there are optimisations (CassandraSparkExtensions) introduced in the Spark Cassandra connector which you should include in your app.
Instead of building with the connector JAR, I suggest specifying the package coordinates for the Spark Cassandra connector with the --packages option so that all dependencies are included in your app.
For example, try launching a PySpark shell with:
$ bin/pyspark \
  --master <spark_master_url> \
  --spark.cassandra.connection.host=cassandra_host_ip \
  --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.4.0
  --conf spark.sql.extensions=com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraSparkExtensions

You can then test your code to see if you can write to Cassandra. Cheers!
